# Application to monitor bandwidth usage per program

Tags: windows, monitoring, bandwidth

I need to monitor the amount of bandwidth a few processes are consuming however these applications don't have the options to do so, is there an application that I can run on Windows Server 2008 that will allow me to monitor the bandwidth usage of these applications?

I've seen a few programs that do this per NIC but I need it per application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Reliability and Performance Monitor MMC snap-in provided in W2K8 to do just this.

See [HERE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755081(WS.10).aspx?ppud=4) for a short guide.

Answer (score 0):

I think [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) supports this.

Comment: I'm a bit weary about NetLimiter it has caused Kernel Panics on my desktop and this is going to be deployed to a server.

Comment: I also only used it on a desktop, but never had any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to track network usage from a few specific processes.  There are Windows perf counters that have some of what you are looking for.  But, you probably will want to look for something to get the per process values.  Try AppFirst.

Answer (score 0):

Should someone stumble upon this answer while looking for the same solution for Windows 7 (as it was in my case), the command to use is `resmon`.